# Running custom Mysql function from php Mysqli_query returns Undefined Index error

Tags: php, mysql

I created a custom MySQL function that generates a 15 character random string.
When I test the function in phpmyadmin it generates the code fine.
However when I run it from PHP it returns an error - "Notice: Undefined index: dex in file.php on line ###".

```php
    $sql1 = "select GenerateRand() as dex;";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
    echo $sql1 . "| |" . $row1['dex'];
```

I have tried the following

- using the different mysqli_fetch options but none return a different result.
- checking the query result for errors;
- mysqli_errno($con) returns 0
- mysqli_error($con) returns ""
- mysqli_num_rows($result1) returns 1
- mysqli_num_fields($result1) returns 1

**SOLVED**

After adding these lines to my code

```php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

I realized that I had not granted my database user the execute PRIVILEGES.

It was still not working so after trying the var_dump again I realized that I needed to be using mysqli_fetch_array if I wanted to use $row['dex'] to retrieve the code.

Thank You all for your ideas.

Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: what does `var_dump($row1);` return?

Comment: changing my echo command to echo $sql1 . "| |" . var_dump($row1);
the result is "NULL select GenerateRand() as dex;| |"

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return status of your query for errors?

Comment: See [How to get MySQLi error information in different environments? / mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments-mysqli-fetch-as)

Comment: Do you need a ';' after dex in the query ?